# Parsing Text in PHP using Regular Expression

Tags: php, regex

Using PHP, how can I remove every thing from this text and get only **165** as a result?

(I need to get any number coming at **165**'s place)

> 1-16 of 165 results for ""luminara flameless candles""

Comment: Regex: `\d+(?= result)`
https://regex101.com/r/vCvMqI/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `preg_match` function:

```
$s = '1-16 of 165 results for ""luminara flameless candles""';
preg_match('/\bof ([0-9]+) results/', $s, $m);
print_r($m[1]);
```

The output:

```
165
```